# Writing statistical models in equation form

Tags: predictive-models, references, regression-strategies

Could anybody suggest an appropriate book or perhaps a short online course concerning appropriately writing statistical models in an equation form?  It is so much better to present models this way (i.e., equation form), accompanied by a description, rather than just describing the model in a text form.

Comment: There's a huge variety of models; presumably you're primarily interested in particular kinds of models; what kinds of models are you dealing with? -- regression models, mixed models, ANOVA, GLMs, time series, etc ?

Comment: Thanks Glen_b.  Primarily regression models, but I am also interested in other models that you mention above.

Comment: I doubt you'll see a book that's about how to write all of those. Indeed in different situations different ways to write may predominate. You may need to focus the scope of your question more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may not be what you are seeking but the marriage of R and LaTeX gives rise to some excellent opportunities for doing this automatically.  Here is an example:

```
require(rms)
set.seed(1)
x <- runif(100)
y <- abs(x - 0.5) + runif(100)
f <- ols(y ~ rcs(x, 5))  # restricted cubic spline, 5 default knots
latex(f, file='')
```

The LaTeX code produced is below, and when you compile into pdf you get the algebraic form of the equation.  This is for a certain class of models and does not allow interactions higher than second order.  The workflow is really elegant when using knitr with R and LaTeX.

```
\[{\rm E({\rm y}}) = X\beta, {\rm \ \ where} \\ \]
\begin{eqnarray*}
    \lefteqn{X\hat{\beta}=}\\
    & & 0.8507352 \\
    & & + 0.4496578{\rm x}-14.84777({\rm x}-0.08356852)_{+}^{3}+84.03212 ({\rm x}-0.334967)_{+}^{3}  \\
    & &  -109.4476({\rm x}-0.4878107)_{+}^{3}+56.68924 ({\rm x}-0.7303781)_{+}^{3}  \\
    & &   -16.42599({\rm x}-0.9084412)_{+}^{3}  \\
    \end{eqnarray*}
and $ (x)_{+}=x {\rm\ if\ } x>0, \ 0 {\rm\ otherwise} $.
```

Comment: Thank you Frank. This is a very interesting approach. I am not that familiar with LaTeX though. I am looking for a book for reference, although approach similar to yours using a software program for automatically outputting equations would be fine too.

Comment: A good starting point for LaTeX is http://tug.ctan.org/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf .  LaTeX is free and is easy to install on Linux and Mac OS.  Windows users tend to use MikTeX which is also free and easy to install.

Comment: Now you can use $\LaTeX$ equations without installing $\LaTeX$ if you use R Markdown or Quarto.  An example is [here](https://hbiostat.org/rflow/analysis.html#sec-analysis-format)

Answer (score 4):

Even with a plain old constant-variance regression model, there's a plethora of ways to write it:

$y=\beta_0+\beta_1x_1+\beta_2x_2+...+\beta_px_p+\epsilon$

$E(y)=\beta_0+\beta_1x_1+\beta_2x_2+...+\beta_px_p$

$y=X\beta+\epsilon$

$E(y)=X\beta$

... (and more besides)

and that's not counting adding in the different ways to write down the model for the variance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late to answer this questions, but [this short document](https://www.medicine.mcgill.ca/epidemiology/joseph/courses/EPIB-621/interaction.pdf) provides a nice and concise explanation of what each element in an equation for linear and multiple linear regression - with and without interactions - means, and how to move into writing more complex models.

Comment: Just a tip - it's a good idea to include more than just a link and explanation of why it's relevant. That link may someday disappear, for starters. It's better to answer the question in detail while also citing the link. :)